# How to set configurations for use in TCA/Overrides or how to configure sys categories?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

For an extension i like to use sys_categories that are stored in a dedicated folder. How do I configure the folder and access the configuration inside the TCA setup?

I tried this approach. I use the method `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable` inside `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_xref_domain_model_project.php`.

Where I place the hardcoded 333 I would like to use a configuration value in the ideal case tsconfig. Is it parsed and accessible at this point?

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable(
   'xref',
   'tx_xref_domain_model_project',
   'areas',
   array(
       'label' => 'Areas',
       'exclude' => FALSE,
       'fieldConfiguration' => array(
           'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.pid = 333',
       )
   )
);
```

Is there a more easy approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable()` in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/<your_table>.php` is exactly the right approach and in fact what [TYPO3 itself does](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/4cb53e828bd5138d180cdf9cac1ccf7fd31086d2/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php).

Comment: Good to know I am on the right track. How to a replace the hardcoded 333 by a configuration? Is TSConfig available at this point?

Answer (score 0):

At least the global extension configuration is accessible at this point.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html

This is not fully satisfying, as you may want to define a different category source folders for different pages or sys_folders. Yet it will do for many projects:

```
$areaFolder = (int)\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ExtensionConfiguration::class)
    ->get('xref', 'areaFolder');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable(
    'xref',
    'tx_xref_domain_model_project',
    'areas',
    array(
        'label' => 'Areas',
        'exclude' => FALSE,
        'fieldConfiguration' => array(
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.pid = ' . (string) $areaFolder,
        )
    )
);
```